# Getting issues while doing a simple tfs migration

Tags: tfs

Can anyone explain me what I am dealing with here, I am doing a simple migration procedure, I have tfs2013 update4 and I am trying to migrate it to vsts, I am using microsoft's migration utility to do it, but when I pass the validation command i.e TfsMigrator.exe  Validate /collection:http://localhost:8080/tfs/java test it gives me error TF255003, it says it can't fetch the installation path please elaborate me whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

That means the **TfsMigrator** is not available for your current version of TFS.

The [official TfsMigrator tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274) is only supported for TFS 2017, you can download the corresponding tool based on your TFS version (RTW_15.105.3924742 or Upate1_15.112.3923436)

So, you need to upgrade to the latest version of TFS (2017 update1) first if you want to use TfsMigrator tool. Please see [Validating a Collection](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-import#validating-a-collection) for details.

Comment: @The Man, Have you resolved the issue? is the answer helpful for you?